# Update table with SQL with rowwise count from columns

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | asthma | diabetes | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -------- | 0 | 1 |  |
| -------- | 1 | 1 |  |

And want to update the last column called "total" with the rowwise totals:

| id | asthma | diabetes | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -------- | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| -------- | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I tried:

UPDATE table_name
SET total = asthma + diabetes END;

then

UPDATE table_name
SET total =
SUM(asthma + diabetes)
GROUP BY id
FROM table_name
END;

but neither work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: `UPDATE table_name SET total = COALESCE(asthma,0) + COALESCE(diabetes,0)` but I don't recommend as violating the normalization rule.

Comment: A row total like this should be a computed / calculated column.

Comment: HI there, thanks very much. I am not sure I understand this - does this add up the asthma and diabetes cells for the ID row? What does the 0 mean? The dataset is ~3 million rows long so I need it to add up the number in the asthma and diabetes columns for each row (i.e. work out how many diseases each person has - the second person/row in the table above has both asthma and diabetes. I need to create a count per person/row of how many diseases each has. I can do this in R but the dataset is so large that R struggles to compute and takes a long time.

Comment: @user19890826 Suggest you read the documentation for `coalesce` and all will become clear.

Comment: Thanks very much. I understand that it returns the first non-null result? I need to add up the totals in each column (the actual database has 60 variables rather than 2) so the total could be between 0 and 60. Not sure if coalesce works for this. This is the guidance I looked at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp, perhaps there is another set of guidance with different information? Thank you again

Comment: You might want to edit your question to add clarity and detail, for example your title mentions *count* but your question is not counting anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that I used 2 years ago for a python project and worked good:

```
UPDATE Customers SET age = COALESCE(customer_id,0) + COALESCE(customer_id,0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As above - I'm not sure what the ,0 is referring to? And how would this code refer to the column names (asthma and diabetes)?

Comment: The 0 is a parameter of the function COALESCE and say to sql the piece of data to extract.
You can adapt my code like that : `UPDATE table_name SET total = COALESCE(athama,0) + COALESCE(diabetes,0);`

Comment: It works! Thanks so much.. Think I understand COALESCE now.. Really appreciate everyone's help here.